# Remove_if with vector containing variants

Tags: c++, c++17, variant

I have two different objects:

```
struct TypeA {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
};

struct TypeB {
    std::size_t no;
    std::string data;
    std::string data2;
    std::string data3;
};
```

They are stored in a `std::vector` with `std::variant`

```
std::vector<std::variant< TypeA, TypeB>> ab;
```

Now i want to remove all elements were the member `no = 0`.

Without the `std::variant` with the vector containing only `TypeA` I would do it like this:

```
ab.erase(std::remove_if(ab.begin(), ab.end(),
    [](const TypeA& a) { return a.no == 0; }), ab.end());
```

But how to incorporate the `std::variant` ? I tried to come up with something with `std::visit` but i cannot ad it in the predicate of `std::remove_if` or can I?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, `std::visit` can help.  The functor passed to `visit` just needs to be able to accept each type of the `variant`, and the easiest way to do that is with a generic lambda:

```
ab.erase(
    std::remove_if(
        ab.begin(),
        ab.end(),
        [](const auto &v) {
            return std::visit(
                [](const auto &obj) { return obj.no == 0; },
                v);
    }),
    ab.end());
```

Here the type of `v` for the outer lambda is always used as `const std::variant<TypeA, TypeB>&`, and `auto` is just more convenient than typing out `std::variant<TypeA, TypeB>`.  But for the inner lambda, it's important that the lambda is generic, because `visit` will instantiate its template `operator()` with both `TypeA` and `TypeB`.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to access the "same" data member of different types, then these types need to be subclasses of a common polymorphic base class defining this data member.

In your case, however, where `TypeA` and `TypeB` are not related, you'll have to make a type-safe access to the respective data member. The solution provided by @aschepler shows this in a generic way using `std::visit` functor; the following solution is without `std::visit` (hence not that elegant, but still working):

```
ab.erase(std::remove_if(ab.begin(), ab.end(),
    [](const std::variant< TypeA, TypeB>& v) { 
      int no;
      if (v.index()==0) {
         no = std::get<0>(v).no;
      } else {
         no = std::get<1>(v).no;
      }
      return no==0;
    }), ab.end());
```

Comment: This is just asking for trouble. What happens when you add a 3rd type to the variant? Do you remember that you need to update this? What if the type you happen to be looking for isn't cheap-to-copy? Or copyable at all? Or default constructible?